# Set up but do not evaluate the integral representing the volume of the region $ax^2 + by^2 = r^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

In my class right now we are doing volumes using cross sections.

The question is:
Set up but do not evaluate the integral representing the volume of the region $$ax^2 + by^2 = r^2$$

It's rotating around an unspecified axis.

I've solved for y:

$ax^2+by^2=r^2$ $\ $$\Rightarrow$ $y=\sqrt{\frac{r^2 -ax^2}{b}}$

Some class mates are saying to set $y=r$ but I don't really understand *why* I would do that or what it would accomplish.

I carried the problem out

$$A(x)= \int_{c}^{d}\left |\sqrt{\frac{r^2-ax^2}{b}}  \right |dx$$
$$V(x)= \pi \int_{c}^{d}\left |(\sqrt{\frac{r^2-ax^2}{b}})^2  \right |dx$$
but i feel like this isn't the correct answer. What should i do?

Comment: Your region is 2D, so it's not going to have a 3D volume. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: So far, the equation you give represents an ellipse in the $ \ xy-$ plane, or an infinite elliptic cylinder extending along the $ \ z-$ axis with elliptical cross-sections.  Is there some other condition(s) given that places boundaries on this volume?

Comment: Sorry! It's rotating around an unspecified axis. I just edited the question to include that.

Comment: In that case, using the "disk method" with rotation about either axis will clear away the radical; the integration is then pretty simple.  By "cross-sections", you can use the "classical" geometric formula for the area of an ellipse, integrate a "stack" of "similar" ellipses (that is, ones of constant proportions) from your choice of coordinate plane up to the endpoint of an axis (Cavalieri's Principle), and double the volume by applying symmetry.  That also produces a rather simple integration.  Any choices are roughly equal amounts of effort and all give the same volume.

Comment: What are the $\large a$ and $\large b$ signs ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation you mention is just an ellipse without 3D information.
I assume that you need the volume for the solid on rotating this along some axis of symmetry, which I represent as
\begin{equation}
ax^{2}+by^{2}+cz^{2}=r^{2}
\end{equation}
Then, the integral for one octant of the solid is
\begin{eqnarray}
V_{1/8}&=&\int_{0}^{r/\sqrt{c}} dV(z)=\int_{0}^{r/\sqrt{c}}A(z)dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{r/\sqrt{c}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{(r^{2}-cz^{2})/b}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{(r^{2}-cz^{2})/a}}\sqrt{\frac{r^{2}-ax^{2}-cz^{2}}{b}}dx\ dy\  dz
\end{eqnarray}

Then $V=8V_{1/8}$.

Comment: With the addition to the qn, the above answer has become useless (as I assumed it to rotate around an axis of symmetry alone.) Is there a way to delete the post?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't clear to me whether this question had been resolved; now that it has been revised to indicate that we are working with an ellipsoid (actually either an oblate or prolate spheroid):

[image]

The region in the plane is an ellipse with the "standard-form" equation,

$$ \frac{x^2}{r^2 / a} \ + \ \frac{y^2}{r^2 / b} \ = \ 1 \ \ , $$

so the ellipse is centered on the origin and has "semi-horizontal" and "semi-vertical" axes of $ \ \frac{r}{\sqrt{a}} \ \text{and} \ \frac{r}{\sqrt{b}} \ , $ respectively.  It's a bit unclear what the intent of the problem is, since rotating an ellipse (unequal lengths of axis) about the $ \ x-$ axis will produce an ellipsoid with a different volume from one produced by rotation about the $ \ y-$ axis.  So we'll address different possibilities.

If we are evaluating the volume by the use of "cross-sections", that presumably means that we are taking "slices", along the $ \ z-$ direction, which all have the same proportions between their axes as has the ellipse in the $ \ xy-$ plane.  If that ellipse is being rotated about the $ \ x- $ axis, the ellipsoid will extend along the $ \ z- $ axis from $ \ -\frac{r}{\sqrt{b}} \ \ \text{to} \ \frac{r}{\sqrt{b}} \ . $  The cross-section of the ellipsoid in the $ \ yz-$ plane is then $ \  \frac{x^2}{r^2 / a} \ + \ \frac{z^2}{r^2 / b} \ = \ 1 \ $ .  Upon solving this equation for $ \ x \ , $ we find that the elliptical cross-section at a height $ \ |z| \ $ has "semi-horizontal axis"  $  \ x \ = \ \sqrt{\frac{r^2 - bz^2}{a}} \ $ ; the "semi-vertical axis" is then $ \ y \ = \ \sqrt{\frac{r^2 - bz^2}{b}} \ $ (as may be found by using the cross-section proportions, or solving the cross-section in the $ \ xz-$ plane for $ \ y \ . $

The area of the elliptical cross-sections in the $ \ z-$ direction are thus given by

$$ \ A(z) \ = \ \pi \cdot \frac{r^2 - bz^2}{\sqrt{ab}} \ . $$

Since the ellipsoid is symmetrical about the $ \ xy-$ plane, we can integrate the "upper half-ellipsoid" and multiply the result by 2 to find the volume,

$$ V \ = \ 2 \ \int_0^{r/\sqrt{b}} \ \ \pi \cdot \frac{r^2 - bz^2}{\sqrt{ab}} \ \ dz \ \ = \ \ \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3 \sqrt{ab^2}} \ \ . $$

For the ellipsoid produced by rotating our ellipse about the $ \ y-$ axis, the cross-section in the $ \ yz-$ plane becomes $ \  \frac{x^2}{r^2 / a} \ + \ \frac{z^2}{r^2 / a} \ = \ 1 \ $ ; an argument analogous to the above leads us to

$$ \ A(z) \ = \ \pi \cdot \frac{r^2 - az^2}{\sqrt{ab}}  $$

and

$$ V \ = \ 2 \ \int_0^{r/\sqrt{a}} \ \ \pi \cdot \frac{r^2 - az^2}{\sqrt{ab}} \ \ dz \ \ = \ \ \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3 \sqrt{a^2b}} \ \ . $$

These look a bit different from the standard ellipsoid volume formulas because of the peculiar form of the given ellipse equation.  Were we to use $ \ a^2x^2 \ + \ b^2y^2 \ = \ a^2b^2 \ , $ our results would become  $ \ \frac{4 \pi}{3}  \ a^2b \ \ \text{and} \ \ \frac{4 \pi}{3}  \ ab^2 \ , $ one being the volume of a oblate, the other, a prolate spheroid, depending upon which of $ \ a \ $ or $ \ b \ $ is larger.  (These of course go over to the formula for the volume of a sphere for $  a \ = \ b \ . $ )